# Iterate over rows in Pandas dataframe to find values in other file and extract index

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have one csv file imported as pandas dataframe with filenames in one column. I have another file which is a numpy array with the same filenames in it but at different indexes. Can you help me with iterating over the filenames in the csv file to find the match in the numpy file and extracting the index where the filename is at in the numpy file.

So for example:

```
d = {'col1': ["Apple", "Peach"], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     Apple 3
1     Peach 4

b = np.array(["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Peach"])
b
array(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Peach'], dtype='<U6')
```

Now i would like to now from every item in the df at what indexes they are in the array so i can append something at that position in another array.

I have tried something like this:

```
for i,j in df:
    if j in b:
        print(b.get_loc)
```

Comment: _Now i would like to now from every item in the df at what indexes they are in the array so i can append something at that position in another array._ Can you provide some more **context** for your program? There might be a better way of doing things. Is `col1` supposed to represent the file names here? What's wrong with the code you tried?

Comment: Yes, i would like to compare filenames in my csv file to the filenames in the array, whenever there is a match i need the index from the array. There is a third array which has data connected to the filenames in the array (so the same indexes). When i get this index i can append more data to the data at the index from the third array

Comment: _append something at that position in another array_ Appending to a NumPy array is really not ideal. Is there any particular reason you're using numpy in the first place? You're storing strings, right?

Comment: I want to train an algorithm with numbers stored in one specific array. These numbers are extracted from files stored in a second array with overlapping indexes (so info from index 1 is info from the same sample at both arrays). There is a third document (csv) which stores the correct answers. So lets say the data from array 1 contains info about a fruit, array 2 contains info about which file this is, and csv file three contains what type of fruit this is. This csv file contains the same filenames as those in the second array. So csv and array 3 can only be linked with the use of array 2

Comment: Just to be sure I understand this correctly: You've got three arrays, one with file names, one with the data from the files, and one with the results. Corresponding data is at the same index in all three arrays? It might help if you share at least a bit more of your program.

Comment: Yes i have 3 files, but 2 of them are arrays and one of them is a csv files. The first array stores numerical info about certain files. The second array has the corresponding filenames for this numerical info. And the third (csv) file contains filenames, at random places, with the correct fruit belonging to it. So i need to connect the right answers inthe csv file to the first array by extracting the matching filenames in the second array.

Comment: _i have 3 files_ 3 **files**? Your arrays are stored in files? _So i need to connect the right answers inthe csv file to the first array by extracting the matching filenames in the second array._ The best way to do that is going to be somewhat specific to your program...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203821/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-koen-wijnen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, we can turn array and df into a dict by indices as their keys and use a function to finding matching pairs :

```py
import collections as colls

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'col_1': ['Apple', 'Peach'], 'col_2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
b = np.array(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Peach'])

d_1 = df['col_1'].to_dict()
d_2 = dict(enumerate(b))


def dicts_to_tuples(*dicts):
    result = colls.defaultdict(list)
    for curr_dict in dicts:
        for k, v in curr_dict.items():
            result[v].append(k)
    return [tuple(v) for v in result.values() if len(v) > 1]


print(d_1)  # {0: 'Apple', 1: 'Peach'}
print(d_2)  # {0: 'Apple', 1: 'Banana', 2: 'Pear', 3: 'Peach'}
print(dicts_to_tuples(d_1, d_2))  # [(0, 0), (1, 3)]
```

the rest is down to you.

you could even turn the array into a datframe and perform a merge :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
merge_ = pd.merge(df,df2,left_on=['col1',df.index],right_on=['col1',df2.index],how='inner')
```

Comment: I could have sworn I had already left a comment. `d2` could just be written `dict(enumerate(b))`. `d1` should just use `Series.to_dict()`.

Comment: Is it alright if I make multiple changes? Want me to run them by you first?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile feel free - I'm a self taught nobody - happy to learn from others.

Comment: Okay, I submitted an edit. I now realize that I don't actually understand part of it, namely the list comprehension in the `return`. Why are you checking if `v` has more than 1 item?

Answer (score 1):

Does this solution work? Do you need to know the corresponding key, if not, this is just the index list:

```
mask = np.in1d(b,df['col1'])
idx = np.arange(len(mask)) 
idx[mask]

# array([0, 3])
```

You can also do this to get a dict of the locations:

```
df['idx'] = idx[mask]                                                                                                                                                                              

df.set_index('idx')['col1'].to_dict()                                                                                                                                                              
# {0: 'Apple', 3: 'Peach'}

df.set_index('col1')['idx'].to_dict()                                                                                                                                                              
# {'Apple': 0, 'Peach': 3}
```

Comment: Don't use `.values`! I'm pretty sure it's unnecessary here, and so is the `.tolist()`. Instead of creating a numpy array from arrange, just use `numpy.arange()`. The default start value for `range()` is 0, so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: You forgot the `.values`. It’s more of a style thing, but I think accessing columns using `[]` is better than `.`.

Comment: Another thing: I believe that you can get rid of `idx` entirely. `mask.nonzero()` should do the trick.